# Why does dialog("open") deselect all previously selected text on screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, selection, jquery-ui-dialog

I asked this a while back with absolutely no luck (or answers).

I do not wish for this to happen. I can initialize the entire dialog but the second that I call

```
theDialog.dialog("open");
```

All previously selected text on the screen is deselected. Technically, speaking, either the selection object is trashed or the range objects boundaries is collapsed - the effect is the same.

I wish for the dialog to be as unobtrusive as possible. Is it possible to have the dialog not effect the user's selection at all?

Is this possibly an issue with events? Is there a way to have the dialog bypass whatever step it is taking that collapses the selection?

Comment: Modal dialogs are inherently obtrusive. Likely, something gets focused in the dialog which changes the active selection. I don't understand why you want an unobtrusive dialog.

Comment: However, it's not impossible to "divide" focus if that is indeed the issue. Right click context menus would be an example, right?

Comment: Most default events, like `onclick` change the active selection. You can have one selection with multiple ranges across multiple elements but that doesn't come into play because the ranges are cleared when the selection changes. Find out if you can stop the dialog from changing the active selection.

Comment: I'll look into preventing the change in active selection. But if the issue is focus could this be remedied by assigning a "selected" class to the range/selection object and the dialog and then giving the class focus priority?